# Trouble connecting to blue-tooth devices using node noble on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using noble module to connect to BT devices, my code works absolutely fine on mac and I am facing some issues on windows. I can scan for the devices, but the state is always powered off, but the same code works well on mac. I have followed all the setup suggested by noble team on windows, but I don't know where I am going wrong, any ideas would be helpful.